# why does my hamcrest "contains" not work as expected?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, hamcrest

I run this line:

```
List<String> ids = new List<String>()
ids.add("id1");
ids.add("id2");
assertThat(ids, contains("id1"));
```

but strangely it returns "fail".

how can I fix this?

Comment: I think you can use assertTrue(ids.contains("id1"));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
assertThat(ids, hasItem(equalTo("id1"));
```

This is because contains will expect you to have a matcher that matches every item in the iterable.

If you look at the api docs [here](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) You can see the difference between contains and hasItem. If your list was as following:

```
List<String> ids = new List<String>()
ids.add("id1");
```

Your assertion would work as you would expect.

Comment: You can drop the call to `equalTo`. All matchers that accept other matchers as parameters will wrap non-matchers with it.

Comment: Yeah you can drop it but it is more readable and more explicit about what you are testing which is why I added it in.